# Updating a global object's attributes .onSnapshot() within a for loop only updates last object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple vanilla JS Firebase app that is, among other things, designed to allow users to store the number of ounces of a given 'commodity' they possess, for example silver or gold. On the client side, the ounces are used in another function `getCommodityValue` to get the total value of each commodity from an API (that's why the function being async).

However, when I attempt to run `updateCommodities` (shown below) to update the values in my `supportedCommodities` object, for some reason only the value for the last commodity listed is changed. The values are accurately represented in Firebase, so it looks like this function is at fault. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a simplified (still non-functioning) version of my code:

```
let supportedCommodities = {
  SILVER: {name: "silver", value: 0},
  GOLD: {name: "gold", value: 0}
}

async function updateCommodities() {
  for (sc in supportedCommodities) {
    let commodityName = supportedCommodities[sc]["name"];
    firebaseDB.collection("commodities").where("name", "==", commodityName)
      .onSnapshot(async (querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.docs.length != 0) {
          const commodityData = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
          supportedCommodities[sc]["value"] = await getCommodityValue(commodityData.ounces, commodityData.name);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP function passes an async function as the onSnapshot() callback, the `getCommodityValue`  promise contained therein can only resolve once.  Replace the onSnapshot call with a get...

```
async function updateCommodities() {
  for (sc in supportedCommodities) {
    const commodityName = supportedCommodities[sc]["name"];
    const query = firebaseDB.collection("commodities").where("name", "==", commodityName);
    const doc = await query.get();
    const commodityData = doc.data();
    supportedCommodities[sc]["value"] = await getCommodityValue(commodityData.ounces, commodityData.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't look like this is the problem. I'm running a query snapshot for each allowed name, and names of documents are unique, so there *should* only be one document in each snapshot. Plus if I just directly output the result of getCommodityValue to the console, it displays the expected value

Comment: @user5824608 - sorry, I should have read and thought more carefully. The issue is that onSnapshot doesn't mix well with promises.  See edit.